# Nginx and PHP-FPM setup - PHP session path file permission problems after every yum update?

Tags: php, session, nginx

After a yum update , session path file permissions were changed on:

```
/var/lib/php/session
```

this becomes owned by "apache" (but I don't even have apache installed)

This caused a failure to create PHP sessions with Nginx/PHP-fpm and disabled phpMyAdmin.

To resolve, every time I have to do this manually :

```
sudo chown root:nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

is there any way or setting that this won't is overwritten by the yum-update process?